# What nationality are the soldiers in these WW2 pictures?

Tags: world-war-two, identification, ww2-european-theater, post-war

These pictures were taken in the immediate post-war, 1945 or 1946 I guess, somewhere in central Europe (Austria, Czech Republic or Poland). I have blurred the faces because the pictures come from a family album. If someone know which car is this, I would also be very thankful !

[image: One man leans against a vehicle containing two uniformed individuals]
[image: Two individuals in uniform beside a vehicle containing two other individuals in uniform]
[image: An individual drives a vehicle; in the background is another individual possibly on a bicycle.]

[image: close-up on the individual uniform's shoulder badge]

[image: Close-up the on individual uniform's cap insignia]

Comment: it is right hand drive, this narrows it down a lot

Comment: they could be foreign nationals visiting a country with right hand drive

Comment: @bigbadmouse - ...assuming the photo images aren't flipped. Probably aren't, since all the cigarettes are being held in right hands.

Comment: @bigbadmouse Much of German transport was captured enemy vehicles and Russia got lorries from UK as Lease-Lend and some French and Polish units were equipped by the UK. So I expect the only army that had only LHD was the US.

Comment: The shoulder patch of the officer looks Soviet, but it could be of any of the satellite armies that they established in Eastern Europe, I guess.

Comment: Could you give us a close up of the shoulder insignia in the 2nd photo?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped with this search so far ! @Schwern, here you have two close-ups of the shoulder and cap insignia of the same officer (this is as goo as it get in terms of resolution and focus).

Comment: @DanielJablonski The shoulder insignia looks like three stars(?) between two stripes. The hat insignia looks like a diamond with four spikes. Is that a good description? Maybe you can confirm with a magnifying glass.

Comment: Car might be a Tatra 57 A or a Tatra 75.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The badge on the brigadier cap is from Czechoslovakia, for example see  [here](https://www.army.cz/en/armed-forces/history/gallery/1945-1948--72091/). The lower rank soldier wears a cap with a smaller badge without a diamond and swords.

The shoulder pad insignia is probably "četař - aspirant" (sergeant - cadet).

The car is a pre-war model of Tatra T57 - for other pictures, see [gallery on TatraPortal.sk](https://www.tatraportal.sk/?ukaz=popisky/t57_sk&lang=sk), especially [this picture](https://www.tatraportal.sk/data/popisky/t57/a/t57a_59.jpg).

Right-side driving (steering wheel on the left) was agreed on by the Czechoslovakia parliament in 1938, but only enacted by German occupiers on 17th March 1939.

Comment: Thank you so much @Edheldil for this amazingly accurate response. As you can see from the comments, we were getting close to the target, but this response seems to be right on target. Any thoughts from the other contributors?